# How to update ldap with ldif backups?

Tags: openldap, ldif

I have an openldap ldif backup file daily that I want to replicate in other server. 
I add the data with `slapadd -v -l file.ldif` but 
can I update the changes that have occurred in my other ldap server with next ldif backup file?

I try with ldapmodify, ldapadd but i does not work properly.

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason all masters are no longer able to synchronize, the [mmldif](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19850-01/816-6400-10/mmldif.html) tool can be used to generate the master database manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably check perl ldap tools. They include utilities as ldapsort and ldapdiff. Which will give you the difference between both the LDAP data.

First sort the data with ldapsort using dn: & then create a diff. It will provide you a ldapmodify ready data, which will replace, add & delete attributes.

Reference: http://search.cpan.org/~gbarr/perl-ldap-0.3202/